# Trying to execute a query I converted from MS ACCESS

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

i've been looking for the error for some time now. thank you in advance for helping!!

Here's the error: Query: SELECT reviewer_cases.case_number, reviewer_cases.reviewer, reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer, reviewer_cases.reviewer_revision_t...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) AS 'Revision Review Cost'
FROM reviewer_cases LEFT JOIN hr_mr ON reviewer_ca' at line 4

```
SELECT reviewer_cases.case_number, reviewer_cases.reviewer, 
reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer, 
reviewer_cases.reviewer_revision_time, hr_mr.mr_hourly_rate, 
hr_mr.operation_type, hr_mr.level, 
IF(hr_mr.level!='MR1',(reviewer_cases.reviewer_revision_time*
(hr_mr.mr_hourly_rate/60)),
IF(hr_mr.level='MR1','5')) AS 'Revision Review Cost'
FROM reviewer_cases LEFT JOIN hr_mr ON reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer = 
hr_mr.alias
WHERE (((reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer) IS NOT NULL) AND 
((hr_mr.operation_type)='MR')) 
OR (((reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer) IS NOT NULL) AND 
((hr_mr.operation_type) IS NULL));
```

[image: review_cases table]

[image: hr_mr table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    reviewer_cases.case_number,
    reviewer_cases.reviewer,
    reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer,
    reviewer_cases.reviewer_revision_time,
    hr_mr.mr_hourly_rate,
    hr_mr.operation_type,
    hr_mr.level,
    IF(hr_mr.level != 'MR1',
        (reviewer_cases.reviewer_revision_time * (hr_mr.mr_hourly_rate / 60)),
        '5') AS 'Revision Review Cost'
FROM
    reviewer_cases
        LEFT JOIN
    hr_mr ON reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer = hr_mr.alias
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND (((reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer IS NOT NULL
        AND hr_mr.operation_type) = 'MR')
        OR (reviewer_cases.revision_reviewer IS NOT NULL
        AND hr_mr.operation_type IS NULL));
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Dands if it resolved your issue,you can upvote it also.

Answer (score 1):

use backticks in MySQL to create columns that have spaces in the name

```
`Revision Review Cost`
```

NOT

```
'Revision Review Cost'
```

or better, don't use spaces in column names

```
Revision_Review_Cost
```

One of your IFs has no "do if false" -> add something, even if it's just NULL